# What is "com mó"?

Tags: tradução, informalidade

A web search reveals a few phrases, e.g. ["To com mó preguiça"](https://cheezburger.com/6238514176)

What does "mó" mean?

Answer (score 3):

The word "mó" in this context appears to be an informal expression standing in the place of "a maior". "To com mó preguiça" would be more formally written out as "estou com a maior preguiça" -- "I am feeling very lazy".

Comment: @Schilive Do you think "mó" is really short for "muito" instead of "a maior"? Both convey the same meaning, but I don't think "muito" is plausible, since here it would be "Eu estou com muita preguiça", not "muito".

I recommend you submit an additional answer :)

Comment: you are right. "Estou com muita preguiça" = "estou com (a) maior preguiça", but "tenho muito jogo" ≠ "tenho (o) maior jogo", and "tenho mó jogo" = "tenho (o) maior jogo"; so "tenho mó jogo" ≠ "tenho muito jogo". Sorry, my mistake.